# Show all rows in grid after clearing filters in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-grid, extjs-stores

I have a data store and a grid. I add filters in the store and they work properly as I see the results in my grid. But once I disable all my filters aka clear them from my store I want to view all my rows in the grid without reloading them from a web service which is a kind of heavy task. All data is already fetched from the service and there is no need to reaload it again.

How can I do this? Is there some function in the store?

Comment: So let me get this straight, you load all of the data from your web service on first load, which probably means you've set up your store to be an `ajax` proxy?  But if you load all of it in one fell swoop, why don't you just make that an actual Ajax call, and make your store a memory store?  Do you rely on the back-end for filtering/sorting?

Comment: Yes, I load all data from the service in one go, one http request. It has finite number of entires so it can be done like this. I filter all data localy, just change the filter. And the store is already memory. And no, I don't rely on the backend for filtering/sorting

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you can do what I said then... or is there some other piece of information I'm missing?

Comment: What function do I call to view all data again in the grid? store.load()? I have all the data in a global variable

Comment: I tried store.filter() with no params, it doesn't work

Comment: Well, if you've got a filter set, and you want to unset it, you would call [`store.clearFilter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter).  Otherwise, I would probably call [`store.reload`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-reload).  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: If reload() doesn't connects to the service, than that is the thing. I will try it now

Comment: Reload uses the last settings from load, so it should work.  If it doesn't, you can always try [`loadData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData) or [`loadRawData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadRawData), as you said you've got the data in a global, but this really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yup made the trick with loadData(). Reload() leaves empty grid :( Anyway thanks. I used a simple trick, when all filters are off, loadData() from the global variable. I will delete the question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already was a similar question with correct answer. In short, you need to call **filter** method without params after setting **remoteFilter** to **false**:

```
store.remoteFilter = false;
store.clearFilter();
store.remoteFilter = true;
store.filter();
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Gmtd/

Comment: I believe that's what [`store.clearFilter(true)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter) does, doesn't it?  So you shouldn't have to be setting their public variable `remoteFilter` directly.

Comment: @incutonez Sorry, but it seems no. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Gmtd/). But if you uncomment the lines code starts to work. If I understand it right, clearFilter just removes filter from the store, but doesn't refresh data snapshot. Filter method calculates new snapshot based on new set of filters (in this case empty one) and remoteFilter variable prevent store to fetch data from a remote server.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like it's supposed to.  The documentation state "For a remotely filtered Store, this means that the filter collection is cleared, but the store is not reloaded from the server," and that's if you supply `true` to clearFilter.  So otherwise, it should reload the data... unless I'm not understanding the problem fully.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your grid's view is not refreshed. Try this:

`mygrid.getView().refresh()`

Comment: Tried it. THe store is empty. That is why I don't see a thing in the grid. Maybe because I use loadData() instead of load()? No initial settings for reload() to work?